# ColorAnimation stuck on color when button is pressed repeatedly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, coloranimation

I have a custom `button-style` with a `ColorAnimation`.

This works fine, but when pressed multiple times repeatedly, it stays stuck on the target color.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="mainButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation 
                                    Duration="0:0:0.10" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                    To="Red"
                                    AutoReverse="True"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set the `From` property on your `ColorAnimation`. So when you press the button in the middle of its animation, the Storyboard takes the current `Foreground` color value as its `From`, and this is the color that the animation reverses back to.

Now when you repeatedly press the button, the `From` color moves closer and closer to red, giving the impression that the color is stuck on red.

---

**Update:**

This answer only points out the problem. Refer to Viv's answer for an elegant solution

Comment: This is indeed whats happening. First it's a faint `white-reddish` color, then pink. ultimately it gets red.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Yeh if you cannot afford to remove the `Storyboard` in `Trigger.ExitActions` then you do indeed have to address the `From` issue for intermediate starting `Storyboard`'s yourself.

However specifying a hard-coded `From` **isn't** the only solution. You can let the animation reset itself to the underlying base color when it's starting up.

The benefit of this is by not specifying a `From` you got one less thing to keep track of with future updates.

```
<Storyboard AutoReverse="True">

  <!-- By not specifying a To or From we pretty much reset the property to un-animated state(Exactly what the hard-coded from does) -->
  <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />

  <!-- This part is same as original time to kick into new Foreground as desired -->
  <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1.5"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                  To="Red" />
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: I tried this, but this makes my `StoryBoard` nearly invisible. It flashes.. I increased the `duration` but it stays the same, `Vanlalhriata's` answer resolved it.

Comment: @DeMama oh yh that's because of the `RemoveStoryboard` being invoked with the Trigger exiting even when animation isn't completed. However specifying a hard-coded `From` isn't the only solution. I've updated my answer with an Alternate approach that lets the Animation do the reset itself by not specifying a From or To Value when the animation starts. Only real benefit of doing this is to not specify a hard-coded `From` and keep track of it for all future updates of the control `Style`